# NPM start not working after adding create react app typescript

Tags: typescript, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to start my create react app(Typescript) and Im always getting this error. I've done all the steps and I have added the .env file(SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true) and I also updated my NPM and even reinstalled it. What should I do?.

```
> Executing task: npm run start <


> my-app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\raahi\OneDrive\Desktop\typescript-react\my-app
> react-scripts start


There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

  "babel-jest": "^26.6.0"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of babel-jest was detected higher up in the tree:

  C:\Users\raahi\node_modules\babel-jest (version: 24.9.0)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If you would prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

  1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
  2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
  3. Remove "babel-jest" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
  4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

  5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
     This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.

  6. Check if C:\Users\raahi\node_modules\babel-jest is outside your project directory.
     For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.

  7. Try running npm ls babel-jest in your project folder.
     This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed babel-jest.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\raahi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-07T19_47_30_824Z-debug.log
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run start" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the same error. If you try to run `npm ls babel-jest` it will list all versions of babel-jest installed in your project. You probably will see that babel-jest is installed with different versions since each dependency installs a different version of babel-jest.

I found a workaround for that in 2 steps:

1. Try to match the versions of dependencies in a way that they use the same version of babel-jest
2. You can use `resolutions` on your package.json to solve the version conflict

```
   "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
        "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.1",
        "babel-jest": "^26.6.0",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.0",
        "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
        "husky": "^4.3.8",
        "jest": "26.6.0",
        "lint-staged": "^11.1.2",
        "typescript": "^4.3.5"
      },
      "resolutions" : {
        "babel-jest": "26.6.0",
        "jest": "26.6.0"
      }
```

When you fix the issue, your `npm ls babel-jest` will look like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've accidentally installed something in your home folder. It looks like you are trying to develop your app inside the `C:\Users\raahi\OneDrive\Desktop\typescript-react\my-app`  folder, but sometime in the past you may have accidentally installed stuff into your home folder `C:\Users\raahi\node_modules\babel-jest`

If you delete the folder `C:\Users\raahi\node_modules` as well as `C:\Users\raahi\package.json` and `C:\Users\raahi\package-lock.json` (if those last 2 files exist), it should solve your problem.